# What is the error in Argument and Input data value

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am beginner to pine script this is a code I coded with support of internet. there is error in this line. how can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCSzo.jpg)

Tis is the complete Code. I highlighted the error line

```
//@version=5
indicator("Main Support and Resistance Levels with Fibonacci", overlay=true)

// Set up input options
period = input('4H', title='Chart Period', type=input.resolution)
**multiplier = input(1, title='Fibonacci Multiplier', type=input.float, minval=0.1, step=0.1)**

getSupportResistanceLevels() =>
    // Get the most recent swing high and swing low on the specified chart timeframe
    swHigh = ta.highest(high, barmerge.gaps_off, period)
    swLow = ta.lowest(low, barmerge.gaps_off, period)

    // Calculate the distance between the swing low and swing high
    distance = swHigh - swLow

    // Calculate the Fibonacci extension level
    extension = distance * multiplier

    // Calculate the main resistance level
    resistance = swHigh + extension

    // Calculate the main support level
    support = swLow - extension

    // Return the support and resistance levels
    [support, resistance]

// Get the support and resistance levels based on the chart timeframe
[support, resistance] = security(syminfo.tickerid, period, getSupportResistanceLevels)

// Plot the support and resistance levels
plot(resistance, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1)
plot(support, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message clearly tells you what the issue is.

You cannot use arguments like `minval`, `maxval` etc. with the `input()` function.

You need to use the `input.float()` function instead.

```
multiplier = input.float(1, title='Fibonacci Multiplier', minval=0.1, step=0.1)
```